# Can't seem to understand why this array won't reverse in C

Tags: arrays, c, loops

I'm having trouble understanding why my reverseArray function won't properly swap the values at the indices.

What I was going for was the last value just swaps with the first value all the way until **i** deprecates to 0. I believe something is wrong with the [(SIZE - i) - 1] but I can't seem to wrap around my head why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MIN 0
#define MAX 100
#define SIZE 40

void fillArray(int arr[]);
int findWithRange(int arr[], int low, int high);
int findMaxInArray(int arr[], size_t arr_size);
void printArray(int arr[], size_t arr_size);
void reverseArray(int arr[]);


int main(void){

  srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
  int arr[SIZE], low, high;
  
  fillArray(arr);
  printArray(arr, SIZE);
  puts("\n");
  puts("\n");
  reverseArray(arr);
  printArray(arr, SIZE);
  puts("\n");
}

void fillArray(int arr[]){
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    arr[i] = rand() % (MAX + 1) + MIN;
  }
}

void reverseArray(int arr[]){
  int temp;
  for (int i = SIZE - 1; i > 0; i--){
    temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[(SIZE - i) - 1];
    arr[(SIZE - i) - 1] = temp;
  }
}
```

Output (Bottom is "Reversed" Array):
[image: output]

Expected Output (similar):
[image: eoutput]

Comment: You shouldn't swap *all* the elements of the array, but only *half* of those. Otherwise you are putting them back in their original position (first the last is swapped with the first and then the "first" is swapped back with the "last").

Answer (score 2):

The first clue I got was the output you got, you'll notice that only the first and last number got swapped but not the middle numbers. In your for loop of the reverse function you went too far. What you need to do is run half the for loop because the middle is where you start swapping the number back to their original places. So:

```
void reverseArray(int arr[]){
  int temp;
  for (int i = SIZE - 1; i > SIZE/2; i--){ // Changed code here
    temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[(SIZE - i) - 1];
    arr[(SIZE - i) - 1] = temp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I did notice that halfway it stopped swapping, just didn't know what to do with that.

Comment: Please, consider pointing out that there is no need to traverse the array backwards and that the reason only the first and the last elements are swapped lies in OP's condition `i > 0`.

Comment: It wouldn't matter forwards or backwards, the reason is not ```i > 0``` the reason is ```i >=0``` that will swap everything